# Где расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*Награждается Иванов Иван ученик 6 класса участник школьного этапа городского конкурса "В стране математике".*

Comment: Эти слова из текста сообщения, или — содержание диплома (грамоты)?

Answer (score 2):

О расстановке запятых хорошо сказано в ПАС.

> Приложения, стоящие **после** определяемого слова, независимо от передаваемого ими значения разделяются запятыми и обязательно выделяются (см. § 61): *Людмила Пахомова, заслуженный мастер спорта, олимпийская чемпионка, чемпионка мира, неоднократная чемпионка Европы...*

**Награждается Иванов Иван, ученик 6 класса, участник школьного этапа городского конкурса...**
*Региональный победитель Всероссийского филологического чемпионата Боровикова Анна, ученица 6 класса, дипломант I степени V Международной олимпиады по русскому языку.*

С этим понятно. Сомнения у меня вызвал сам конкурс.
Если слово "математика" является названием страны (то есть топонимом), то его надо писать с заглавной буквы: *«В стране **М**атематике».*
Если же имеется в виду дисциплина, то получается словосочетание с родительным падежом "страна (чего?) математики" и при склонении изменяется только первое слово: *«В стране математик**и**»*.

[Знаки препинания при однородных приложениях](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=115#pp115)
[Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)

Answer (score 1):

Награждается Иванов Иван, **ученик 6 класса, участник школьного этапа городского конкурса "В стране математике".**

1) Обособляется приложение, стоящее после имени собственного (из правил Розенталя). Здесь после имени собственного два однородных приложения.

2) Вообще говоря, все проблемы с обособлением приложений и определением их однородности появляются в том случае, если приложения находятся перед определяемым словом. Если ряд приложений расположен **после определяемого слова**, то он всегда обособляется и считается однородным, например:

Обломов, **дворянин родом, коллежский секретарь чином,** безвыездно живёт двенадцатый год в Петербурге.

На конференции с интересным докладом выступил Леонов С.А., **доцент, кандидат биологических наук**.

3) Вопрос № 292192
Здравствуйте! **У меня вопрос по оформлению почетных грамот.**

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Верно: **Награждается Иванов Иван Иванович, водитель предприятия Х (город У),** за многолетний добросовестный труд.

Answer (score -1):

Довольно непростая тема. Здесь необходимы знания тем "Обособленное приложение" и "Уточняющие члены предложения". Теперь разберемся, как их различить.

1. В нашем случае видим, что одно имя является собственным, а другое — нарицательным, что довольно важно. Найдем связь между двумя понятиями:

"Награждается Иванов Иван, (кто он ЕЩЁ такой?) ученик шестого класса..."

Здесь основным именем выступает Иванов Иван, а сочетание "ученик" необходимо для его характеристики. Иван просто является учеником. Нельзя задать вопрос "кто именно?", т.к. фактически есть и другие учащиеся. Чтобы не грузить вам голову, просто приведу ещё один пример:

"Ученик шестого класса Иванов Иван ..."

Получаем, что "ученик шестого класса" (важно писать всё сочетание, чтобы сохранить распространённость приложения) является распространённым приложением, стоящим ДО главного слова, выраженного собственным именем. В предыдущем же случае у нас была обратная картина. Вот в этом случае необходимо поставить запятую.
"Участник городского этапа..." обособляется не только по этим же правилам, но и по однородности с другим приложением.

Возможная "ловушка": некоторые могут принять оба сочетания за уточнение(и это самый "безобидный" вариант разбора), что неверно. Собственно, для этого я сначала начал объяснять теорию. Однако в авторских текстах можно встретить и иной смысл(однако письменно это задокументировано не будет), зависящий от определенных условий.

Comment: Какой сатанист снял балл?